# Hibernate 4 schema update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am migrating from Hibernate 3.x to Hibernate 4 in my Spring MVC project. In Hibernate 3 I used to have the following code:

```
AnnotationSessionFactoryBean bean = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
bean.setPackagesToScan(myPackages);
bean.setHibernateProperties(props);
bean.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
bean.setSchemaUpdate(true);
```

but as far as I've read, AnnotationSessionFactoryBean was replaced with LocalSessionFactoryBean in Hibernate 4 (please correct me if I am wrong). But LocalSessionFactoryBean do not have setSchemaUpdate method so I was wondering how I can set LocalSessionFactoryBean to recreate my DB schema automatically?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add the appropriate hibernate property to the Hibernate properties (see `getHibernateProperties()`): `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update`

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#configuration-misc-properties